# How to use HTML Entities with Right to Left translated page layout (Arabic)?

Tags: html, localization, translation, right-to-left, html-entities

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this error regarding HTML entities with right-to-left direction (Arabic localization).

I'm trying to translate 
`"By clicking continue, you agree to",`

The arabic google translation is:
`"بالنقر فوق &quot;متابعة&quot;، فإنك توافق على",`

But when applying to the rtl page, it reverses the order of  `&quot;` and gives me `;quot&`

How can I bypass the rtl specifically for the html entity for quotation marks only so it appears as: `"متابعة"` while still using the html entity?

Comment: Are you using auto translation in your website ? or this is hand version ?

Comment: we translate by hand

Comment: as Arabic native speaker , we don't use `&quot;` at all when we wanna quot some words . we use the known symbol "__" . I don't know why google translate it like so.
The part you translated should be like that :
`بالنقر على زر "متابعة" فانك توافق على`
or you can eliminate the quot and I suggest to wrap the word `متابعة` inside `<span>` element and later make it bold or different color with css. this would be better UX on my opinion.

Comment: if my last comment dosen't make sense for you plz share some code on original question because even I use `&quot;` instead of `"` I can't reproduce your problem...thanks